# Is the framework provided by this paper for checking the constraints of AI systems really new?

Tags: neural-networks, papers, research

The authors of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.04714v1.pdf) paper present a framework for checking the constraints of AI systems using formal argumentative logic between 2 agents: an interrogating agent and a suspect agent. The interrogating agent is attempting to find contradictions in the responses of the suspect agent by querying about information and the suspect agent must provide all the relevant information.

Is this framework really new? I am pretty certain that I saw a very similar framework in the context of program verification some years ago.